# \openin error using \includecollection from package collect

Tags: errors

I'm writing a package for a software design document. There is a section related to software interfaces between modules, and another section to describe each module. Here there is a summary of interfaces (functions and variables) used by module, collected from previous section using the package `collect`.

I've created some macro to create interfaces (and collecting needed info), and others to place collected info into desired place, but compiling the document gives me multiple occurrences of following error:

```
! You can't use a prefix with `\openin'.
<to be read again> 
                   \openin 
l.306 \insertprovidedinterfaces{SUP}
```

Typing `r` run pdfLaTeX to the end, and the result is exactly what is expected, but I'm not able to understand/get rid of this messages.

Any hints?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} 
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{collect}
\usepackage{tikz}%
\usepackage{hyperref}
%%
\colorlet{IFcolor}{Yellow!30!Blue!20}
\colorlet{IFVcolor}{Yellow!80!Blue!20}
%
% definitions of variables containing modules list, later used
% to avoid re-defining an already defined collection
% pfun -> provided functions
% nfun -> needed functions
% pvar -> provided variables
% nvar -> needed variables
\def\pfuncollectionlist{}
\def\nfuncollectionlist{}
\def\pvarcollectionlist{}
\def\nvarcollectionlist{}
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% environment for interfaces - functions
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Usage: 
% param 1: Provider acronym
% param 2: name of function including ()
% param 3: comma-separated caller list
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\NewDocumentEnvironment{int-interface}{mmm}%
{%before
  \phantomsection\label{iifprovided#1-#2}%
  % provided function interfaces
  \newpfuncollection{#1-provided-fun}%  
  \begin{collect} {#1-provided-fun}{}{}% 
  \item \hyperref[iifprovided#1-#2]{#1\_#2}
  \end{collect}%
  % 
  % needed function interfaces
  \def\callers{#3}
  \foreach \caller in \callers%
  {%
    \newnfuncollection{\caller-needed-fun}%  
    \begin{collect}{\caller-needed-fun}{}{}% 
    \item \hyperref[iifprovided#1-#2]{#1\_#2}%
    \end{collect}%
}%
%
\small     
\longtable[htbp]{>{\columncolor{IFcolor}}p{3.5cm}p{12cm}}\kill%\toprule
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\footnotesize\emph{Follows from previous page}} \\
\endhead
% normal foot
\multicolumn{2}{r}{\footnotesize\emph{Continue in the next page}} \\
\endfoot
% last foot
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
%
% here the stationary contents
\toprule
Syntax & #1\_#2 \\
}%
{%
%after
Callers & #3 \\%
\endlongtable
}%
%
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% environment for interfaces - variables
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Usage: 
% param 1: Provider acronym
% param 2: name of variable
% param 3: comma-separated caller list, read access
% param 4: comma-separated caller list, write access
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\NewDocumentEnvironment{int-interface-var}{mmmm}%
{%before
  \phantomsection\label{iifprovided#1-#2}%
%  provided function interfaces
  \newpvarcollection{#1-provided-var}%  
\begin{collect}{#1-provided-var}{}{}% 
\item \hyperref[iifprovided#1-#2]{#1\_#2}
\end{collect}%
%
%
% needed interfaces 
% two consecutive \foreach are used to decide whether writing R, W or R/W
% first loop search for every read caller in writecaller list; 
% if read caller is found in writecallers list, 
% a 'R/W' is appended; elsewhere, it is 'only' R. 
% Then similar thing is done starting from writecaller list:
% if actual writecaller is NOT found in readcaller list, it is marked only W;
% elsewhere nothing has to be done, because R/W has been already treated in 
% previous loop (RW)
\def\callersreadlist{#3}
\def\callerswritelist{#4}
% detecting RW or R
\foreach \readcaller in \callersreadlist
{
  \IfSubStr{\callerswritelist}{\readcaller}
  {
    \newnvarcollection{\readcaller-needed-var}%  
    \begin{collect}{\readcaller-needed-var}{}{}% 
    \item \hyperref[iifprovided#1-#2]{#1\_#2} [Read/Write]
    \end{collect}%
  }%
  % else%
  {%
    \newnvarcollection{\readcaller-needed-var}%  
    \begin{collect}{\readcaller-needed-var}{}{}% 
    \item \hyperref[iifprovided#1-#2]{#1\_#2} [Read only]
    \end{collect}%
  }%
}
% detecting W  
\foreach \writecaller in \callerswritelist
{
  \IfSubStr{\callersreadlist}{\writecaller}
  {
    % if found, nothing to do
  }%
  % else%
  {%
    \newnvarcollection{\writecaller-needed-var}%  
    \begin{collect}{\writecaller-needed-var}{}{}% 
    \item \hyperref[iifprovided#1-#2]{#1\_#2} [Write only]
    \end{collect}%
  }%
}   
%
% write longtable
\small    
  % didascalia ed etichetta
\longtable[htbp]{>{\columncolor{IFVcolor}}p{3.5cm}p{12cm}}\kill%\toprule
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\footnotesize\emph{Follows from previous page}} \\
\endhead
% piede normale
\multicolumn{2}{r}{\footnotesize\emph{Continue in the next page}} \\
\endfoot
% piede finale
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
%
% here the stationary contents
\toprule
Syntax & #1\_#2 \\%
}%
{%
%after
% do the same search as before, to build list of read only, write only and read/write access modules
\def\callersreadlist{#3}%
\def\callerswritelist{#4}%
Accessed by: & %
\foreach\readcaller in \callersreadlist
{%
  \IfSubStr{\callerswritelist}{\readcaller}%
{%
    % if found
\readcaller{} \accessmode{rw}$\quad$%
}%
  % else%
{%
\readcaller{} \accessmode{r}$\quad$%
}%
}%
%  
%
\foreach\writecaller in \callerswritelist
{%
  \IfSubStr{\callersreadlist}{\writecaller}%
{%
}%
  % else%
{%
\writecaller{} \accessmode{w}$\quad$%
%
}%
}%
\\   
\endlongtable
}%
%
%
%
%
%
\newcommand{\accessmode}[1]{%
  (#1),
}%
%
\DeclareRobustCommand{\insertprovidedinterfaces}[1]{%
  \paragraph{Function interfaces}
  \IfSubStr{\pfuncollectionlist}{#1}{%
%    Collection '#1-provided-fun' exists
    \begin{itemize}
      \includecollection{#1-provided-fun}%
    \end{itemize}
  }{%   
    None.
  }%
  \paragraph{Variable interfaces}
  \IfSubStr{\pvarcollectionlist}{#1}{%
%    Collection '#1-provided-var' exists
    \begin{itemize}
      \includecollection{#1-provided-var}%
    \end{itemize}
  }{%   
    None.
  }%
}%
%
\DeclareRobustCommand{\insertneededinterfaces}[1]{%
  \paragraph{Function interfaces}
  \IfSubStr{\nfuncollectionlist}{#1}{%
%    Collection '#1-needed-fun' esists
    \begin{itemize}
      \includecollection{#1-needed-fun}%
    \end{itemize}
  }{%   
    None.
  }%
  \paragraph{Variable interfaces}
  \IfSubStr{\nvarcollectionlist}{#1}{%
%    Collection '#1-needed-var' esists
    \begin{itemize}
      \includecollection{#1-needed-var}%
    \end{itemize}
  }{%   
    None.
  }%
}%
%
\DeclareRobustCommand{\newpvarcollection}[1]{%
  \IfSubStr{\pvarcollectionlist}{#1}{%
  }{%
    \xdef\pvarcollectionlist{\pvarcollectionlist{} #1}
    \definecollection{#1}%
  }%
}%
%
\DeclareRobustCommand{\newnvarcollection}[1]{%
  \IfSubStr{\nvarcollectionlist}{#1}{%
  }{%
    \xdef\nvarcollectionlist{\nvarcollectionlist{} #1}
    \definecollection{#1}%
  }%
}%
%
\DeclareRobustCommand{\newpfuncollection}[1]{%
  \IfSubStr{\pfuncollectionlist}{#1}{%
  }{%
    \xdef\pfuncollectionlist{\pfuncollectionlist{} #1}
    \definecollection{#1}%    
  }%
}%
%
\DeclareRobustCommand{\newnfuncollection}[1]{%  
  \IfSubStr{\nfuncollectionlist}{#1}{%
  }{%
    \xdef\nfuncollectionlist{\nfuncollectionlist{} #1}
    \definecollection{#1}%
  }%
}%
%
\begin{document}
\section{Interfaces}
Here some software interfaces:
\begin{int-interface}{SUP}{eGetActualSystemStatus}{ICP}
  Parameters  & None                                        \\
  Return type & System status code. Codified value          \\
  Purpose     & Obtain actual system status from \emph{SUP} \\
\end{int-interface}
%
\begin{int-interface}{SUP}{eSetOverrideRequest()}{SMB}
  Parameters  & Request code: ENTER, EXIT                   \\
  Return type & Operation result. Codified value.           \\
  Purpose     & To set an override request to \emph{SUP}    \\
\end{int-interface}
%
\begin{int-interface-var}{HAL}{ausInputVoltageSamples}{SENS, I2C}{I2C, ICP}
  Type           & Buffer of 5 samples \\
  Purpose        & To store acquired input voltage samples\\
\end{int-interface-var}
%
\section{Modules description}
Some descriptive stuff\ldots

\subsection{SUP module}
Other descriptions\ldots

Here is a list of provided interfaces:
\insertprovidedinterfaces{SUP}

\subsection{HAL module}
Other descriptions\ldots

Here is a list of provided interfaces:
\insertprovidedinterfaces{HAL}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can patch the commands of `collect.sty` that seem responsible for the error in your application. This shouldn't concern other uses of `collect`:

```
\makeatletter
\def\CE@ensure@opened#1{%
  \@ifundefined{ifCE@@#1@open}{%
    \PackageError{collect}{Collection `#1' has not been defined}{\@ehc}%
  }{%
    \csname ifCE@@#1@open\endcsname\else
    \immediate\expandafter\openout\csname CE@@#1@out\endcsname=\jobname.#1\relax
    \@ifundefined{CE@@#1@opentrue}{}{\global\csname CE@@#1@opentrue\endcsname}%
    \fi
  }%
}
\def\CE@ensure@closed#1{%   
  \@ifundefined{ifCE@@#1@open}{%
    \PackageError{collect}{Collection `#1' has not been defined}{\@ehc}%
  }{%
    \csname ifCE@@#1@open\endcsname
    \immediate\expandafter\closeout\csname CE@@#1@out\endcsname
    \@ifundefined{CE@@#1@openfalse}{}{\global\csname CE@@#1@openfalse\endcsname}%
    \fi
  }%   
}   
\makeatother
```

The code should go in the preamble; your MWE seems to run without errors.

---

The following seems a correct reimplementation of your minimal example (same document syntax) without using `collect`, but exploiting `expl3`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} 
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tikz}%
\usepackage{hyperref}
%%
\colorlet{IFcolor}{Yellow!30!Blue!20}
\colorlet{IFVcolor}{Yellow!80!Blue!20}
%
% definitions of variables containing modules list, later used
% to avoid re-defining an already defined collection
% pfun -> provided functions
% nfun -> needed functions
% pvar -> provided variables
% nvar -> needed variables

\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \g_cbe_pfuncollectionlist_clist
\clist_new:N \g_cbe_nfuncollectionlist_clist
\clist_new:N \g_cbe_pvarcollectionlist_clist
\clist_new:N \g_cbe_nvarcollectionlist_clist
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% environment for interfaces - functions
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Usage: 
% param 1: Provider acronym
% param 2: name of function including ()
% param 3: comma-separated caller list
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\NewDocumentEnvironment{int-interface}{mmm}
 {
  \cbe_int_interface_start:nnn {#1}{#2}{#3}
 }
 {
  \cbe_int_interface_end:nnn {#1}{#2}{#3}
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \cbe_int_interface_start:nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \phantomsection\label{iifprovided#1-#2}%
  % provided function interfaces
  \cbe_newpfuncollection:n { #1 }%  
  \cbe_collect:nn {#1-provided-fun}{\item \hyperref[iifprovided#1-#2]{#1\_#2}}
  % needed function interfaces
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #3 }
   {
    \cbe_newnfuncollection:n { ##1 }%  
    \cbe_collect:nn {##1-needed-fun}{\item \hyperref[iifprovided#1-#2]{#1\_#2}}
   }
  %
  \small
  \longtable[htbp]{>{\columncolor{IFcolor}}p{3.5cm}p{12cm}}\kill%\toprule
  \endfirsthead
  \multicolumn{2}{l}{\footnotesize\emph{Follows~from~previous~page}} \\
  \endhead
  % normal foot
  \multicolumn{2}{r}{\footnotesize\emph{Continue~in~the~next~page}} \\
  \endfoot
  % last foot
  \bottomrule
  \endlastfoot
  % here the stationary contents
  \toprule
  Syntax & #1\_#2 \\
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \cbe_int_interface_end:nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  Callers & #3 \\
  \endlongtable
  }
%
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% environment for interfaces - variables
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Usage: 
% param 1: Provider acronym
% param 2: name of variable
% param 3: comma-separated caller list, read access
% param 4: comma-separated caller list, write access
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\NewDocumentEnvironment{int-interface-var}{mmmm}
 {
  \cbe_int_interface_var_start:nnnn {#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}
 }
 {
  \cbe_int_interface_var_end:nnnn {#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \cbe_int_interface_var_start:nnnn #1 #2 #3 #4
 {
  \phantomsection\label{iifprovided#1-#2}
  % provided function interfaces
  \cbe_newpvarcollection:n { #1 }
  \cbe_collect:nn {#1-provided-var}{\item \hyperref[iifprovided#1-#2]{#1\_#2}}
  % needed interfaces 
  % two consecutive \foreach are used to decide whether writing R, W or R/W
  % first loop search for every read caller in writecaller list; 
  % if read caller is found in writecallers list, 
  % a 'R/W' is appended; elsewhere, it is 'only' R. 
  % Then similar thing is done starting from writecaller list:
  % if actual writecaller is NOT found in readcaller list, it is marked only W;
  % elsewhere nothing has to be done, because R/W has been already treated in 
  % previous loop (RW)
  % detecting RW or R
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #3 }
   {
    \clist_if_in:nnTF { #4 } { ##1 }
     {
      \cbe_newnvarcollection:n { ##1 }
      \cbe_collect:nn { ##1-needed-var }{ \item \hyperref[iifprovided#1-#2]{#1\_#2} [Read/Write] }
     }
     {
      \cbe_newnvarcollection:n { ##1 }
      \cbe_collect:nn { ##1-needed-var }{ \item \hyperref[iifprovided#1-#2]{#1\_#2} [Read~Only] }
     }
   }
  % detecting W  
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #4 }
   {
    \clist_if_in:nnF { #4 } { ##1 }
     {
      \cbe_newnvarcollection:n { ##1 }
      \cbe_collect:nn { ##1-needed-var }{\item \hyperref[iifprovided#1-#2]{#1\_#2} [Write~only]}
     }
   }
  % write longtable
  \small    
  % didascalia ed etichetta
  \longtable[htbp]{>{\columncolor{IFVcolor}}p{3.5cm}p{12cm}}\kill%\toprule
  \endfirsthead
  \multicolumn{2}{l}{\footnotesize\emph{Follows from previous page}} \\
  \endhead
  % piede normale
  \multicolumn{2}{r}{\footnotesize\emph{Continue in the next page}} \\
  \endfoot
  % piede finale
  \bottomrule
  \endlastfoot
  %
  % here the stationary contents
  \toprule
  Syntax & #1\_#2 \\
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \cbe_int_interface_var_end:nnnn #1 #2 #3 #4
 {
  % do the same search as before, to build list of read only, write only and read/write access modules
  Accessed~by: & 
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #3 }
   {
    \clist_if_in:nnTF { #4 } { ##1 }
     {
      ##1 ~ \cbe_accessmode:n { rw } \quad
     }
     {
      ##1 ~ \cbe_accessmode:n { r } \quad
     }
   }
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #4 }
   {
    \clist_if_in:nnF { #3 } { ##1 }
     {
      ##1 ~ \cbe_accessmode:n { w } \quad
     }
   }
  \\   
  \endlongtable
 }
%
\cs_new_protected:Npn \cbe_accessmode:n #1
 {
  (#1),
 }
%
\NewDocumentCommand{\insertprovidedinterfaces}{m}
 {
  \paragraph{Function~interfaces}
  \clist_if_in:NnTF \g_cbe_pfuncollectionlist_clist { #1 }
   {
    % Collection '#1-provided-fun' exists
    \begin{itemize}
      \cbe_includecollection:n {#1-provided-fun}
    \end{itemize}
   }
   {
    None.
   }
  \paragraph{Variable~interfaces}
  \clist_if_in:NnTF \g_cbe_pvarcollectionlist_clist { #1 }
   {
    % Collection '#1-provided-var' exists
    \begin{itemize}
      \cbe_includecollection:n {#1-provided-var}
    \end{itemize}
   }
   {
    None.
    }
 }
%
\NewDocumentCommand{\insertneededinterfaces}{m}
 {
  \paragraph{Function interfaces}
  \clist_if_in:NnTF \g_cbe_nfuncollectionlist_clist { #1 }
   {
    % Collection '#1-needed-fun' esists
    \begin{itemize}
      \cbe_includecollection:n {#1-needed-fun}
    \end{itemize}
   }
   {
    None.
   }
  \paragraph{Variable~interfaces}
  \clist_if_in:NnTF \g_cbe_nvarcollectionlist_clist { #1 }
   {
    % Collection '#1-needed-var' esists
    \begin{itemize}
      \cbe_includecollection:n {#1-needed-var}%
    \end{itemize}
   }
   {
    None.
   }
 }
%
\cs_new_protected:Npn \cbe_newpvarcollection:n #1
 {
  \clist_if_in:NnF \g_cbe_pvarcollectionlist_clist { #1 }
   {
    \clist_gput_right:Nn \g_cbe_pvarcollectionlist_clist { #1 }
   }
  \cbe_newcollection:nn { #1 } { provided-var }
 }
%
\cs_new_protected:Npn \cbe_newnvarcollection:n #1
 {
  \clist_if_in:NnF \g_cbe_nvarcollectionlist_clist { #1 }
   {
    \clist_gput_right:Nn \g_cbe_nvarcollectionlist_clist { #1 }
   }
  \cbe_newcollection:nn { #1 } { needed-var }
 }
%
\cs_new_protected:Npn \cbe_newpfuncollection:n #1
 {
  \clist_if_in:NnF \g_cbe_pfuncollectionlist_clist { #1 }
   {
    \clist_gput_right:Nn \g_cbe_pfuncollectionlist_clist { #1 }
   }
 \cbe_newcollection:nn { #1 } { provided-fun }
 }
%
\cs_new_protected:Npn \cbe_newnfuncollection:n #1
 {
  \clist_if_in:NnF \g_cbe_nfuncollectionlist_clist { #1 }
   {
    \clist_gput_right:Nn \g_cbe_nfuncollectionlist_clist { #1 }
   }
  \cbe_newcollection:nn { #1 } { needed-fun }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \cbe_newcollection:nn #1 #2
 {
  \tl_if_exist:cF { g_cbe_collection_#1-#2_tl }
   { \tl_new:c { g_cbe_collection_#1-#2_tl } }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \cbe_collect:nn #1 #2
 {
  \tl_gput_right:cn { g_cbe_collection_#1_tl } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \cbe_includecollection:n #1
 {
  \tl_use:c { g_cbe_collection_#1_tl }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\section{Interfaces}
Here some software interfaces:
\begin{int-interface}{SUP}{eGetActualSystemStatus}{ICP}
  Parameters  & None                                        \\
  Return type & System status code. Codified value          \\
  Purpose     & Obtain actual system status from \emph{SUP} \\
\end{int-interface}
%
\begin{int-interface}{SUP}{eSetOverrideRequest()}{SMB}
  Parameters  & Request code: ENTER, EXIT                   \\
  Return type & Operation result. Codified value.           \\
  Purpose     & To set an override request to \emph{SUP}    \\
\end{int-interface}
%
\begin{int-interface-var}{HAL}{ausInputVoltageSamples}{SENS, I2C}{I2C, ICP}
  Type           & Buffer of 5 samples \\
  Purpose        & To store acquired input voltage samples\\
\end{int-interface-var}
%
\section{Modules description}
Some descriptive stuff\ldots

\subsection{SUP module}
Other descriptions\ldots

Here is a list of provided interfaces:
\insertprovidedinterfaces{SUP}

\subsection{HAL module}
Other descriptions\ldots

Here is a list of provided interfaces:
\insertprovidedinterfaces{HAL}
\end{document}
```

I maintain four clist variables, for checking whether the interfaces already exist and each function and variable description is added to a token list variable called `\g_cbe_<interface>-provided-fun_tl`, `\g_cbe_<interface>-needed-fun_tl`, `\g_cbe_<interface>-provided-var_tl`, `\g_cbe_<interface>-needed-var_tl`, that is then used when `\insertprovidedinterfaces{<interface>}` is called.

At least for the example I get the same result as yours.

[image]

Comment: I've put your code in my package, it works perfectly even on the full document. Maybe this can be included (don't know how) in an update of the `collect` package? I've contacted the author, but unfortunately he seems no more involved in its maintenance...

Comment: @cbe I believe it's the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: Can you suggest a better way for doing that? I was in hurry when searching a package to do the work, so I initially stopped my search at the first working solution...

Comment: @cbe I've added a reimplementation using `expl3`

Comment: Just tested on the whole document, runs perfectly. I'm going to study expl3 right now :)

Comment: @cbe It's just a waste of time writing and reading files; the information is better stored in token list and clist variables. The `\foreach` cycles are better done with `\clist_map_inline:nn` that passes for execution each of its element. This is even safer than your method of checking for substrings: here I check for an interface to be in the clist variable, so you can also have interface "A" and interface "AB".

Comment: yes, you're right and we're aware of that... To avoid messing up the question with unrelated things I didn't tell that name collision should be (hopefully :) ) avoided by our coding rules. Anyway now the working folder is cleaner :)

Answer (score 1):

It is a *far* from *minimal* example and I don't know what the intended output should look like, but

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\insertprovidedinterfaces}[1]{%
\begingroup
\let\oldopenin\openin
\def\openin{\def\zzzz{}\oldopenin}

  \paragraph{Function interfaces}
  \IfSubStr{\pfuncollectionlist}{#1}{%
%    Collection '#1-provided-fun' exists
    \begin{itemize}
      \includecollection{#1-provided-fun}%
    \end{itemize}
  }{%   
    None.
  }%
  \paragraph{Variable interfaces}
  \IfSubStr{\pvarcollectionlist}{#1}{%
%    Collection '#1-provided-var' exists
    \begin{itemize}
      \includecollection{#1-provided-var}%
    \end{itemize}
  }{%   
    None.
  }%
\endgroup}%
```

makes the error go away. Probably it is just masking a mis-use of `\openin` elsewhere in the code.

Comment: Your solutions works on the (not) MWE (sorry for that), but, on the full document, pdfLaTeX freezes after a while, and seem waiting for something. I've managed to get it work by adding `\let\openin\oldopenin` before `\endgroup`, restoring the original behaviour after my command has been processed. Thanks!

Comment: With `\tracingall` I get that `\CE@@SUP-provided-fun@openfalse` is undefined, so `\csname CE...\endcsname` changes it into `\relax`; hence TeX sees `\global\relax\fi\@input`; `\fi` disappears and `\@input` is expanded: it starts with `\openin`. So the problem is in the undefined conditional `\ifCE@@SUP-...` that seems due to a misuse of `collect` macros.

Comment: @egreg yes that's about where I gave up too:-)

Comment: The problem seems to be in the fact that `\definecollection` is called inside an environment.

Comment: @egreg: `\definecollection` is called from an environment in which I check if a collection already exists before trying to create it. My intention was to allow users to write new interfaces without worrying if collection that will contain its name was already defined or not. Is there something wrong in my code that I can't see?

Comment: @cbe `\definecollection` defines a couple of things, but the definitions are *local*, so they are lost when the group is ended. You're calling it inside `\foreach` and each `\foreach` cycle is in a group, so the definitions are lost. I don't really know whether this is the problem, but it seems likely.